# how to jump to next matching result which show in "Location list" more efficiently,when using cscope in VIM?

Tags: vim, cscope

how to jump to next matching result which show in "Location list" more  efficiently,when using cscope in VIM?

hi, all:
  I have tried these commands to jump to next result,but not work:

```
      | ø      | SHIFT   | CTRL
------+--------+---------+---------
<F11> | :cprev | :cpfile | :colder
<F12> | :cnext | :cnfile | :cnewer
```

so, I still do it by the still way:

1. `<c-w>` `j`: go to the location list(Quickfix list?)
2. `j`      : locate to next  line
3. `[enter]`: go to browse the details

when using source insight, I just need to press <F9> but do the same things.

I want a hotkey to do this.

Comment: I have tried `ln` and `lp` also.it will not work again.

Comment: What is the value of `'cscopequickfix'`? Check by doing `:set cscopequickfix?`. By default the value of `'cscopequickfix'` is blank meaning  cscope results will not be put into the quickfix list. For more help see `:h 'cscopequickfix'` and `:h cscopequickfix`.

Comment: the value is :  cscopequickfix=s-,g-,d-,c-,t-,e-,f-,i-

Comment: I have a plug change quickfix list to location list. so it works:
```noremap <up> :lprevious<CR>
noremap <down> :lnext<CR>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the following in my vimrc:

```
nnoremap <F5> :cp<CR>
nnoremap <F6> :cn<CR>
```

Comment: I have a plug change quickfix list to location list. so it works: noremap <up> :lprevious<CR> noremap <down> :lnext<CR>. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have a pluging change quickfix list to location list, which name cscope.vim(brookhong). so it work after mapping this:

`noremap <up> :lprevious<CR> 
noremap <down> :lnext<CR>`